# Android - write to a file . Can't find the file

Tags: stream, fileoutputstream

I'm new to android, so this might be prety basic. 
    I'm trying to write data into a file, yet I can not find the file in the device. 
    I'm trying to get the file in the following directory:
    "Computer\Nexus 5\Internal storage\Android\data\application name"

I have tried different method but none of them has worked:

```
FileOutputStream stream;
        try {
            stream = openFileOutput(filename,Context.MODE_APPEND | Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            stream.write(string.getBytes());
            stream.close();
        }catch(IOException e){

        }}
```

and

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/data/" + packageName + "/files/";

try {
            boolean exists = (new File(path )).exists();

                if (!exists) {
                    new File(path ).mkdirs(); 
                }
                // Open output stream
                FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(path + filename,true);
                // write integers as separated ascii's
                fOut.write((Integer.valueOf(content).toString() + " ").getBytes());

                // Close output stream
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I have added the permission in the manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.proLeague"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE"/>
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
    <group gid="media_rw" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable= "true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I thought maybe the file is logged properly but I need to pull it out from the ADB, is that possible?

Comment: One more thing, If I am trying to run option number two then when I debug it I see that the directory of path  is /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/android/data..
Isn't it strange ?

Answer (score 0):

I had manage to solve my issues on my own :

Evantually the code was fine, the problem was that on my nexus 5 phone I need to reboot the phone before I search for new files in the flash storage.
I saw in some blogs it is pretty common.